# HttpContext.Current.Session is null when routing requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, session-variables

Without routing, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is there so I know that the `StateServer` is working. When I route my requests, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is `null` in the routed page. I am using .NET 3.5 sp1 on IIS 7.0, without the MVC previews. It appears that `AcquireRequestState` is never fired when using the routes and so the session variable isn't instantiated/filled.

When I try to access the Session variables, I get this error:

`base {System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException} = {"Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>.`

While debugging, I also get the error that the `HttpContext.Current.Session` is not accessible in that context.

--

My `web.config` looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <pages enableSessionState="true">
      <controls>
        ...
      </controls>
    </pages>
    ...
  </system.web>
  <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" mode="StateServer" timeout="22" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

Here's the IRouteHandler implementation:

```
public class WebPageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public string m_VirtualPath { get; private set; }
    public bool m_CheckPhysicalUrlAccess { get; set; }

    public WebPageRouteHandler(string virtualPath) : this(virtualPath, false)
    {
    }
    public WebPageRouteHandler(string virtualPath, bool checkPhysicalUrlAccess)
    {
        m_VirtualPath = virtualPath;
        m_CheckPhysicalUrlAccess = checkPhysicalUrlAccess;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (m_CheckPhysicalUrlAccess
            && !UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(
                   m_VirtualPath,
                   requestContext.HttpContext.User,
                   requestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod))
        {
            throw new SecurityException();
        }

        string var = String.Empty;
        foreach (var value in requestContext.RouteData.Values)
        {
            requestContext.HttpContext.Items[value.Key] = value.Value;
        }

        Page page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
                        m_VirtualPath, 
                        typeof(Page)) as Page;// IHttpHandler;

        if (page != null)
        {
            return page;
        }
        return page;
    }
}
```

I've also tried to put `EnableSessionState="True"` on the top of the aspx pages but still, nothing.

Any insights? Should I write another `HttpRequestHandler` that implements `IRequiresSessionState`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Got it. Quite stupid, actually. It worked after I removed & added the SessionStateModule like so:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
      ...
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Simply adding it won't work since "Session" should have already been defined in the `machine.config`.

Now, I wonder if that is the usual thing to do. It surely doesn't seem so since it seems so crude...

Comment: Thanks for this. It solved my problem nicely - as it turns out, the production server needed it but not the dev machine.

Comment: That's ins@ne!  Thanks.  This fixed my "TempData" (mvc razor) values from disappearing as well (since TempData uses Session).  Holy Moly.

Comment: I have the issue of TempData values disappearing, but this didn't solve it.

Comment: Just fixed my TempData's issue. I had to change `sessionState` on web.config to use `StateServer` instead of the default `InProc`.

Answer (score 25):

Just add attribute `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to `system.webServer\modules` in web.config.

This attribute is enabled by default in MVC and Dynamic Data projects.

Comment: Awesome! this is the answer i was after .. much better than the accepted one.

Comment: Read some shanselman to know why rammfar can be bad for your (server's) health: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Answer (score 16):

`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true` is actually a real bad solution. This increased the load time of my application by 200%. The better solution is to manually remove and add the session object and to avoid the run all managed modules attribute all together.

Answer (score 11):

None of these solutions worked for me. I added the following method into `global.asax.cs` then Session was not null:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

Comment: And why does this help? :^)

Comment: @user2173353 For me, this helped because I was trying to access SessionState in an object during a web.api request.  I assume it did not previously work because the SessionState was not included in the HttpContext of that specific kind of request.

Comment: @jaybro Yes, I know that too now, after some investigation I did. WebAPI has session state disabled by default and you need to enable it yourself if you wan to use it. However, if you don't use it as `ReadOnly`, the user requests will not get executed in parallel, because each request of the same user locks the session state dictionary to prevent race conditions. I tried having different `SessionStateBehavior` per endpoint, to only use `Required` when needed, but the framework worked against me.

Answer (score 3):

What @Bogdan Maxim said.  Or change to use InProc if you're not using an external sesssion state server.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) for more info on the SessionState directive.

Comment: SessionState works if I access the page normally. If I use routing, HttpContext.Current.Session is null. The <sessionState> section seems to be working in the config.

Answer (score 3):

Nice job!  I've been having the exact same problem.  Adding and removing the Session module worked perfectly for me too.  It didn't however bring back by HttpContext.Current.User so I tried your little trick with the FormsAuth module and sure enough, that did it.

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have forgotten to add your state server address in the [config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) file.

```
 <sessionstate mode="StateServer" timeout="20" server="127.0.0.1" port="42424" />
```

Comment: Tried it but still the same. It shouldn't really matter w/ its default value:"tcpip=loopback:42424"(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.stateconnectionstring.aspx)

I doubt the problem is in the Session provider since it works without the routing.

Answer (score 0):

The  config section seems sound as it works if when pages are accessed normally. I've tried the other configurations suggested but the problem is still there.

I doubt the problem is in the Session provider since it works without the routing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this part of code make changes to the context.

```
 Page page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
                        m_VirtualPath, 
                        typeof(Page)) as Page;// IHttpHandler;
```

Also this part of code is useless:

```
 if (page != null)
 {
     return page;
 }
 return page;
```

It will always return the page wither it's null or not.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. That was some vestigial code after trying out so many things. :D

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a reference to System.web.mvc dll in the session adapter, and adding the same fixed the issue.

Hopefully it will help someone else going through same scenario.

Comment: What does this mean? What are the steps to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your question. What steps are you talking about? I added a reference to "System.web.mvc dll" by right clicking on references on mvc project inside visual studio

Answer (score -1):

a better solution is

runAllManagedModulesForAllRequest is a clever thing to do respect removing and resinserting session module.

alk.

Comment: Please, read this to understand why this is not a clever solution:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/back-to-basics-dynamic-image-generation-aspnet-controllers-routing-ihttphandlers-and-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests