# HttpContext.Current.Session is null when injecting it to interceptor / or using in inside interceptor (mvc4 webapi)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor

I have mvc4 WebAPI application with castle Windsor interception.
The interceptor class needs `HttpContext.Current.Session`.
When I call it directly from the interceptor, it is null.
So I read here that I need to inject the Session and not just access it in the interceptor.

This the code I ended up with...

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel));
            this.RegisterDependencyResolver();
            this.container.Install(new WindsorWebApiInstaller());
}

public class WindsorWebApiInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{

  public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
  {
     // the following interceptor needs Session object
     container.Register( Component.For<IInterceptor>()
                     .ImplementedBy<SecurityInterceptor>()
                     .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                     .Named("SecurityInterceptor"));

     // session is null here, So Castle wont inject it and throw exception...
     container.Register(
         Component.For<HttpSessionStateBase>().UsingFactoryMethod( 
                   () => new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session)).LifestylePerWebRequest());
  }
}
```

Is there any other way to access the session from the interceptor?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always forget that WEBAPI is not MVC.
this is not castle issue.

this did the trick!

```
public override void Init()
{
    this.PostAuthenticateRequest += MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
    base.Init();
}

void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
        SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038669/936651
+1 to @Soren