# Enable session in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I know REST should be stateless.

My Web Api is at the same project of my MVC Website. How can I share the session between them?

I'm trying to use the goodies of Web Api 2 and work with Ajax rather than build a RESTful API.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478244/asp-net-web-api-session-or-something)

in global.asax add the following:

```
public override void Init()
{
    this.PostAuthenticateRequest += MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
    base.Init();
}

void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
        SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented in the same way you have explained, but still, session value is getting reset to null when next call comes.

can you please help me out?

Comment: @ChiragThakar Make sure you check the session after the constructor of your controller has been completed. During constructor the session is not yet available.

Comment: Simply the best