# MVC - Access Sessions From Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api

Using MVC

Naturally, after authentication in a Web API, I want to assign `session("LoggedIn")` the value `True`.

But the session in my Web API keeps returning `NullReference`.

Any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: This will help you surely.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478244/asp-net-web-api-session-or-something

Answer (score 0):

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static string UrlPrefix         { get { return "api"; } }
        public static string UrlPrefixRelative { get { return "~/api"; } }

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: WebApiConfig.UrlPrefix + "/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    ...

    protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        if (IsWebApiRequest())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
    }

    private bool IsWebApiRequest()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith(WebApiConfig.UrlPrefixRelative);
    }

}
```

for more details [Accessing Session Using ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 0):

You need to Sets the type of **session state behavior** that is required in order to support an **HTTP request**.

You can do the changes in **Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()** in **Global.asax** file.

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace Sample
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        }

        protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {           
            HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);           
        }       
    }
}
```