# Using session in MVC controller returns error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use `Session` but the normally way i do its not working.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("FiltroSiltDet")]
public HttpResponseMessage FiltroSiltDet(string DT_INCLUSAO)
{
    try
    {
        HttpSessionState Session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        Session["DT_INCLUSAO"] = "test";
        Session["DT_INCLUSAO"] = DT_INCLUSAO;
        List<AcompanhamentoSiltDetDTO> retorno = new List<AcompanhamentoSiltDetDTO>();

        using (AcompanhamentoSiltBLL oBLL = new AcompanhamentoSiltBLL())
        {

            retorno = oBLL.AcompanhamentoSiltTransacaoDet(DT_INCLUSAO);
        }
        var resp = Request.CreateResponse<List<AcompanhamentoSiltDetDTO>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, retorno);
        return resp;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I always used session this way and its not working now.
When it try to pass value to the session I get this error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Someone know what why its not working.

I'm using a MVC application, I Always used this session method in web Forms I'm new in Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: Show the exact error message and line where it happens. Also are you sure you want to throw a new exception like that?

Comment: I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when it try to pass value to the session in "Session["DT_INCLUSAO"] = "test"

Comment: Are you sure that you enable session? Calls like `AddSession` and `UseSession` in `Startup`?

Comment: Yes,still not working, the controllers is inside a API, i'm almost sure that's why doesn't work.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11479021/1365663, I hope it will help you.

Comment: @ViniciusCano what does  `does not work mean`? In what scenario are you calling the action? how was the service configured? Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Not much help can be provided otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I used Session in my MVC application controller by adding SessionState attribute to controller class, Please try this...

Add [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)] attribute to your class

now this should work

Session["DT_INCLUSAO"] = "test";

Session["DT_INCLUSAO"] = DT_INCLUSAO;