# Session perish in web API

Tags: asp.net, session, request, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to store some value in session from Web API 2 although is is against REST basic principle. But session lost with each request. It is a web form + web API project.

Added below code in Global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
```

Adding session data in one controller as  below.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["ABC"] = "text";
```

With each request/api call, session lost.

I need to set the session in Web API and access  it in Web Form.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478244/asp-net-web-api-session-or-something) answer, but getting error like "*Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'*
"

Comment: As an improvement, instead of using session, you may want to look at object caching using Memcache. You can select a unique key (depending upon the user primary key) for the caching that object and cache the data. Here is the nuget package for memcahe with dot net. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnyimMemcached/   You can set the cache duration same as session timeout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Session Using ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api)