# Access WebForms ASPX Page Session in ApiController

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-web-api, webforms, session-state

I am trying to access the Session in Controllers which are part of a webform project. All the session variables are set on ASPX pages

```
Session["SESSION_KEY_UI_CULTURE"] = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
```

Now on API request from client i need to read Session Variables and perform a task but Session is always null.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/accounts")]
    public class AccountsController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("config")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetCompanyConfig()
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                //Session is always NULL
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

I have tried removing and adding SessionStateModule in WebConfig file

```
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web Api is meant for REST Services which are by definition stateless. Adding the Session back into Web Api defeats the purpose of having a RESTful API.
You may want to reconsider what you're trying to achieve and find another way to solve your Problem.

But there is a way to do what you want:

To activate Session nontheless add the following to your Global.asax

**C#**

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest() {
 HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

**VB**

```
Sub Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required)
End Sub
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478244/asp-net-web-api-session-or-something) are 2 Topics that are going into the same direction which you might want to look at for further information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038669/2672863
Solution worked for me. Hacky way but required in my scenario. Thanks for help.