# How to read ASP.NET_SessionId in Web API Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webforms, axios

We have a legacy ASP.NET WebForms project that I am trying to modernize by using Web APIs instead of the traditional [WebMethod] statics on Code-Behind (because it is just so limited).

However, I wanted to be able to read the Session Cookie in the Web API as well. Before, I can read it in the Code-Behind by accessing the `HttpContext.Current.Session["NAME_OF_COOKIE_HERE"]` and then casting it to a Model - I don't know how to do this with Web APIs.

I'm using axios to talk to my Web API Controllers.

I've added the `withCredentials: true` to my axios config but how do I move forward from there? How exactly can you read the session cookie in Web API Controllers?

Here's a sample:

```
// Client for testing
axios.get(API_ENDPOINT_URL_HERE, {withCredentials: true}).then(res => res).catch(err => err);
```

```
// Web API Controller
[Route(API_ENDPOINT_URL_ACCESSIBLE_BY_THE_CLIENT_TESTING)]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult SOME_FUNCTION_NAME() {
  var currentUser = // I don't know what to do from here on.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in this link: [ASP.NET Web API session or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478244/asp-net-web-api-session-or-something)

Specifically, adding the following in the Global.asax.cs

```
public override void Init()
{
    this.PostAuthenticateRequest += MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
    base.Init();
}

void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
        SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read cookie just like any header property in httpRequestMessage by  HttpRequestMessage.Headers .Please follow the link with proper implementation 
[WebAPI: Getting Headers, QueryString and Cookie Values](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/apr/15/webapi-getting-headers-querystring-and-cookie-values)
Also please note that if you expect a cookie in the Request then use "Cookie" header key and if you are making an rest api call and trying to find cookie in response then use "Set-Cookie"