# Getting an ApiController to work with areas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have 2 areas in my ASP .NET MVC 5 project. One is called *Supporters*, and one is called *Chatter*. In each of these two areas, there is an `ApiController` named `CommunicationController`, and this poses a problem due to the nature of how an `ApiController` works with routing.

### An example of the problem

If I had just one `ApiController` named `CommunicationController` in an area, its routing wouldn't include the area in the URL, and the URL would be something like this:

http://example.com/api/communication/someAction

But in the above URL, where is the area?

Since two of my controllers are named the same, they both have routing issues now.

### What have I tried?

I tried following the instructions here: http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/

They seem to apply for ASP .NET MVC 4 RC, which is no longer relevant since I am using MVC 5, and that might be why it wasn't working.

However, to recap from that blogpost, here are my routing files.

**App_Start\RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}",
            new {action = "Index", controller = "Home"},
            new[] { "Website.Controllers" }
            );
    }
}
```

**App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //the two lines below were added.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SupportersApi", "api/supporters/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional, area = "Supporters"}
            );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ChatterApi", "api/chatter/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, area = "Chatter" }
            );
    }
}
```

**Areas\Chatter\ChatterAreaRegistration.cs**

```
public class ChatterAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Chatter"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        //the below line was added.
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Chatter_api", "api/chatter/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, area = "Chatter" }
            );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Chatter_default",
            "Chatter/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
}
```

**Areas\Supporters\SupportersAreaRegistration.cs**

```
public class SupportersAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Supporters";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        //the below line was added.
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Supporters_api", "api/supporters/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, area = "Supporters" }
            );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Supporters_default",
            "Supporters/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what are my options?

Comment: don't forget you can debug your routes with [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It will give you valuable info as to why your routes aren't working as you expect.

Comment: Glimpse didn't help me. It just crashes when I load the page.

Comment: This might not be what you wanted to hear, but I personally would never use Areas. It is just not worth the effort. If i want to use "areas" I'll just setup the folder structure I want and related Views/Web.configs as necessary. I've found too many things just friction with areas whereas using native MVC and working with it is better. One of the best projects I ever led (using your terms) I had `/Modules/Chatter` and `/Modules/Supporters` with Controllers/Views folders nested. Only cost was I needed to do `public ActionResult foo() { return View("~/modules/chatter/foo.cshtml") }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [WebAPI 2 attributes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), since you are using MVC 5, and you can get rid of a lot of that boilerplate code by declaring the routes for your API along with it's implementation (you can also specify verbs for HTTP actions, and even use attributes to auto-convert to XML/JSON/serialization-of-the-month).

Unless you are using areas for some other reason, you really don't need them to implement a Web API.

In particular, what you want is the RoutePrefix attribute.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work. I now have the `Route` and `RoutePrefix` attributes set, but I get a 404 now when I try to access the URL.

Comment: Try this guide http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 use [RoutePrefix("/api/whatever")] above the CLASS and then [Route("myname")] above the ACTION. use [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] above the action as well.

Comment: That's not working either. I already did that, and I still get a 404. [This](http://i.imgur.com/3MCU6eX.png) is my configuration.

Comment: Don't forget to add config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in the WebApiConfig.cs in App_Start

Comment: @Mathias There could be several problems, and without knowing what all is in your project, I can't really form a good theory as to why you get 404.  In the link I sent, they have a guide to upgrade your solution from WebAPI1 to 2.  I recommend setting up a barebones example based on the tutorials on MSDN, and then comparing with your code.

Answer (score 4):

If two or more areas has apicontroller with same name, then in order to invoke controller in specific area, the area name must be included in URL.

So **http://example.com/api/communication/someAction** wont work.

In this case, it can be
**http://example.com/supporters/api/communication/someAction** and **http://example.com/chatters/api/communication/someAction**

The custom httpcontrollerselector given in http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely works fine with mvc5 too.

**Remove following lines in webapiconfig**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SupportersApi", "api/supporters/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional, area = "Supporters"}
        );        

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ChatterApi", "api/chatter/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, area = "Chatter" }
        );
```

**Here are the steps, which works fine**

**1. Add following extension method to the project.**

```
public static class AreaRegistrationContextExtensions
{
public static Route MapHttpRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string routeTemplate)
{
    return context.MapHttpRoute(name, routeTemplate, null, null);
}

public static Route MapHttpRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string routeTemplate, object defaults)
{
    return context.MapHttpRoute(name, routeTemplate, defaults, null);
}

public static Route MapHttpRoute(this AreaRegistrationContext context, string name, string routeTemplate, object defaults, object constraints)
{
    var route = context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name, routeTemplate, defaults, constraints);
    if (route.DataTokens == null)
    {
        route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }
    route.DataTokens.Add("area", context.AreaName);
    return route;
}
```

}

**2. In each AreaRegistration file, add route which includes area name in routeTemplate**

To SupportAreaRegistration, add

```
 context.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Supporters_DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "supporters/api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

To ChatterAreaRegistration, add

```
 context.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Chatters_DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "chatters/api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Its context.MapHttpRoute, not context.Routes

**3. Add custom HttpControllerSelector**

```
 public class AreaHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
    {
    private const string AreaRouteVariableName = "area";

    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>> _apiControllerTypes;

    public AreaHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _apiControllerTypes = new Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>>(GetControllerTypes);
    }

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return this.GetApiController(request);
    }

    private static string GetAreaName(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var data = request.GetRouteData();
        if (data.Route.DataTokens == null)
        {
            return null;
        } 
        else 
        {
            object areaName;
            return data.Route.DataTokens.TryGetValue(AreaRouteVariableName, out areaName) ? areaName.ToString() : null;
        }
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type> GetControllerTypes()
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        var types = assemblies
            .SelectMany(a => a
                .GetTypes().Where(t =>
                    !t.IsAbstract &&
                    t.Name.EndsWith(ControllerSuffix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
            .ToDictionary(t => t.FullName, t => t);

        return new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>(types);
    }

    private HttpControllerDescriptor GetApiController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var areaName = GetAreaName(request);
        var controllerName = GetControllerName(request);
        var type = GetControllerType(areaName, controllerName);

        return new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, type);
    }

    private Type GetControllerType(string areaName, string controllerName)
    {
        var query = _apiControllerTypes.Value.AsEnumerable();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName))
        {
            query = query.WithoutAreaName();
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.ByAreaName(areaName);
        }

        return query
            .ByControllerName(controllerName)
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .Single();
    }
}

public static class ControllerTypeSpecifications
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> ByAreaName(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> query, string areaName)
    {
        var areaNameToFind = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ".{0}.", areaName);

        return query.Where(x => x.Key.IndexOf(areaNameToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> WithoutAreaName(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> query)
    {
        return query.Where(x => x.Key.IndexOf(".areas.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> ByControllerName(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Type>> query, string controllerName)
    {
        var controllerNameToFind = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ".{0}{1}", controllerName, AreaHttpControllerSelector.ControllerSuffix);

        return query.Where(x => x.Key.EndsWith(controllerNameToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

**4. Make change in Application_Start method in Global.Asax file, in order to use AreaHttpControllerSelector instead of DefaultHttpControllerSelector**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new AreaHttpControllerSelector(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty reasonable solution (not that i actually tested the code) but this is exactly why i don't use areas. So much additional lifting for no value gain.

Comment: I tried following these exact instructions, but I still get a 404.

Comment: in line  `var types = assemblies
            .SelectMany(a => a
                .GetTypes().Where(t =>
                    !t.IsAbstract &&
                    t.Name.EndsWith(ControllerSuffix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
            .ToDictionary(t => t.FullName, t => t);` I get an exception `{"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."}` , Any Idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Try the below configuration. The trick here is to register the namespace to search for the API Controllers when the route matches.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "chatterApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/chatter/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "", controller = "", namespaces = new string[] { "WebApplication.chatter.api" } }
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "supportersApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/supporters/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "", controller = "", namespaces = new string[] { "WebApplication.supporters.api" } }
        );
```

Comment: You can't do this for API controllers.

Comment: For an `ApiController` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using MVC5 and it comes with WebAPI 2.0, you can use

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Supporters/Communication")]
```

to specify the area as @Clever Neologism mentioned. But dont forget to call

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

while configuring the roouting in Global.asax.cs. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094584/multiple-controller-types-with-same-route-prefix-asp-net-web-api) answer

Comment: This is not working. I still get a 404. [This](http://i.imgur.com/3MCU6eX.png) is my configuration.

Comment: Use `Route("AllSessions")` instead of using `Route(Name="AllSessions")` because `Name` param is for different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It has error, route. DataTokens is read-only, can't set value