# Accessing api controller method contained within an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-apicontroller

Obviously I am doing somethign wrong.  Hence this question.

I have a MVC5 asp.net c# web app.

I have created an Area called 'Admin' in my solutions.

I have added an api controller class to my Controllers folder.

I have added a method inside it.

I have added a route to this method.

When I use a browser (in the actual server) to test this I get an error saying not found.

This is what I type in my browser:

```
https://my domain/Admin/Plan/List
```

This is the api class:

```
[RoutePrefix("Admin")]
public class StripeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/Plan/List")]
    public string List()
    {
       //return something
    }
}
```

I have found a similar question on SO here:

[similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332599/getting-an-apicontroller-to-work-with-areas)

but as i can see i have implemented this?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: How are you handling `https` does it work over `http`?

Comment: Did you enable attribute routing for the Admin area?

Comment: Have you call [MapHttpAttributeRoutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479134%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in your `Application_Start`

Comment: @NikolaiDante yes both. but it should work with https as well as I have a certificate and it works with other api calls that are not under the area

Comment: @ChrisPickford I belive it adds that automatically when the area is created but that was the whole point of adding routes?

Comment: @Troopers this is already set in the WebApiConfig file at the root of this app

Comment: Can you add the contents of your Application_Start() method?

Comment: @ChrisPickford hi, where would that be please? I just did a search and that method is nowhere.  thanks

Comment: Global.asax - it's the app entry point.

Comment: @ChrisPickford durrh of course ti is,. will update question - thanks - need coffee!

Comment: I'm not sure but i think the first slash in your route remove the route prefix. Try without the first slash

Comment: @Troopers is was worth a go but that did nto work :(

Comment: @AndrewSimpson You needn't `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` in your `Application_Start` if you use `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` in `WebApiConfig`. Perhaps this fail your routing

Comment: @Troopers the thing is, if I put my controller api in the usual place of controllers folder but NOT within an area it works. I have googled quiet a bit and it seems to be an issue. There seems to be a 'fudge' to do this but it will not support complex objects which is what I use in my app. so given up on areas for api controller

Comment: @AndrewSimpson controller api support compex objects if they are serialisable with json

Comment: I am talking in the context of using areas though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103826/discussion-between-troopers-and-andrew-simpson).

Comment: that is kind of you but at work and not got the time (or permission) I had initially thought of creating an area for 'tidyness' sake but more hassle than it is worth. I have now removed the area thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your areas after your have configured routing, e.g. change your `Application_Start()` to be:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Presuming you are calling `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in your `RouteConfig` class.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. I tried it and did not work I am afraid. And yes, I have MapMvcAttributeRoutes() in my RouteConfig class. But the more relevant thing to do is to put   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); in my WebApiConfig class which I have done