# Accessing SessionState from custom MvcRouteHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
public class CustomRoutingHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
  protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  {

     requestContext.HttpContext.Session is NULL;
     //Is there any way to access Session from there ?

     return FindHttpHandler(requestContext);
     // In created handler Session is not null
  }
}
```

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218057/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-when-routing-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are encountering this issue: see http://www.heartysoft.com/aspnet-routing-iis7-remember-modules.

The solution is to remove and add session state module again.

Also see the related SO question: [HttpContext.Current.Session is null when routing requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218057/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-when-routing-requests)