# ASP.NET Session Lost When Use Web Garden Settings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, iis-7.5, web-garden

I have an ASP.NET MVC (.NETFramework 4.5) application, when I hosted (IIS-7.5), I set `max Worker process` to 5, And Set Session State to `StateServer` And Set a static `machinekey`, after all my session is null,

Why?

Is there any settings that I lost?

any suggestion?

Comment: Check this out which might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218057/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-when-routing-requests

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I found is so wired, when I use web-garden or web-farm the object that stored in session must be `serializable` but in regular we don't need this.

So I just add a `serializable` attribute above the object that stored in session and all things is OK!.