# Trouble installing Umbraco v7.1.7

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco and having trouble getting it working. I have downloaded the manual installation and have set my connection string to a sql express database. When I run the solution it just loads up a picture of the developer conference with a "loading" type animation at the bottom. Am I missing something really obvious here? I have checked my connection string in another project and it works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="urlrewritingnet" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
    <section name="microsoft.scripting" type="Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Configuration.Section, Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="clientDependency" type="ClientDependency.Core.Config.ClientDependencySection, ClientDependency.Core" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="Examine" type="Examine.Config.ExamineSettings, Examine" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="ExamineLuceneIndexSets" type="Examine.LuceneEngine.Config.IndexSets, Examine" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
    <sectionGroup name="umbracoConfiguration">
      <section name="settings" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.UmbracoSettings.UmbracoSettingsSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="BaseRestExtensions" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.BaseRest.BaseRestSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="FileSystemProviders" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.FileSystemProvidersSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="dashBoard" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.Dashboard.DashboardSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <umbracoConfiguration>
    <settings configSource="config\umbracoSettings.config"/>
    <BaseRestExtensions configSource="config\BaseRestExtensions.config"/>
    <FileSystemProviders configSource="config\FileSystemProviders.config"/>
    <dashBoard configSource="config\Dashboard.config"/>
  </umbracoConfiguration>
  <urlrewritingnet configSource="config\UrlRewriting.config"/>
  <microsoft.scripting configSource="config\scripting.config"/>
  <clientDependency configSource="config\ClientDependency.config"/>
  <Examine configSource="config\ExamineSettings.config"/>
  <ExamineLuceneIndexSets configSource="config\ExamineIndex.config"/>
  <log4net configSource="config\log4net.config"/>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- 
      Umbraco web.config configuration documentation can be found here: 
      http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/using-umbraco/config-files/#webconfig
      -->
    <add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value=""/>
    <add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd"/>
    <add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/"/>
    <add key="umbracoPath" value="~/umbraco"/>
    <add key="umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath" value="true"/>
    <add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="true"/>
    <add key="umbracoTimeOutInMinutes" value="20"/>
    <add key="umbracoDefaultUILanguage" value="en"/>
    <add key="umbracoUseSSL" value="false"/>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="config\log4net.config"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN"/>
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=umbraco;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <!-- Important: If you're upgrading Umbraco, do not clear the connection string / provider name during your web.config merge. -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe"/>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="127.0.0.1" userName="username" password="password"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <!--
      If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
      you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
      change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
      of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <pages enableEventValidation="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="umbraco" namespace="umbraco.presentation.templateControls" assembly="umbraco"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco"/>
      <add name="ClientDependencyModule" type="ClientDependency.Core.Module.ClientDependencyModule, ClientDependency.Core"/>
      <add name="ImageProcessorModule" type="ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule, ImageProcessor.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.api, umbraco"/>
      <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.wordApi, umbraco"/>
      <add verb="*" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core "/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" batch="false" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines"/>
        <add extension=".vbhtml" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines"/>
        <add extension=".razor" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <!-- Membership Provider -->
    <membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <!-- Role Provider -->
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
      <remove name="UrlRewriteModule"/>
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter"/>
      <remove name="UmbracoModule"/>
      <add name="UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco"/>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <remove name="ClientDependencyModule"/>
      <add name="ClientDependencyModule" type="ClientDependency.Core.Module.ClientDependencyModule, ClientDependency.Core"/>
      <!-- Needed for login/membership to work on homepage (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218057/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-when-routing-requests) -->
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
      <add name="ImageProcessorModule" type="ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule, ImageProcessor.Web"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <remove name="Channels"/>
      <remove name="Channels_Word"/>
      <remove name="ClientDependency"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" name="Channels" preCondition="integratedMode" path="umbraco/channels.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.api, umbraco"/>
      <add verb="*" name="Channels_Word" preCondition="integratedMode" path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.wordApi, umbraco"/>
      <add verb="*" name="ClientDependency" preCondition="integratedMode" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core"/>
    </handlers>
    <!-- Adobe AIR mime type -->
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".air"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
    </staticContent>
    <!-- Ensure the powered by header is not returned -->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!-- Old asp.net ajax assembly bindings -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- Ensure correct version of MVC -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- Ensure correct version of HtmlAgilityPack -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.4.5.0-1.4.6.0" newVersion="1.4.6.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try to follow the installation instructions here, don't set up a connection string in the web.config before installing :  http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/

Comment: Hi Sebastiaan. Those are the instructions I followed, but it doesn't seem to work. When I tried using the web platform installer it installed into into my documents rather than where I wanted it, that is why I am trying the manual route. I used this: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/install-umbraco-manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sebastiaan's answer was correct. I removed the connection string and it worked.