# My umbraco6 site gets filled with spammy html files

Tags: security, umbraco, spam, umbraco6

I'm having problems with my Umbraco 6 (6.0.5) site that is running on IIS. Someone is exploiting it in some way and keeps uploading spammy html files to it. I get a lot of traffic to these files, which is not what I want and google webmaster tools have given me hacking attempt notices.

I have erased the files several times but they keep coming back. I have also followed some of umbraco's security advice and removed the Install folder, etc. I am also about to upgrade to umbraco 7, but havent had the time to do so yet. Sometimes there are completely new subfolders with files uploaded and sometimes files are added to already current folders.

This is not really my area of expertice. I need to know what can be done to prevent this and also if anyone else have had these problems.

Please advice on what can be done. Am I missing something in my web.config or is it something else?

Here is my web.config. One thing to do is the modify the customErrors flag, but surely this isnt enough

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="urlrewritingnet" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    <section name="microsoft.scripting" type="Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Configuration.Section, Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />

    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="umbraco.presentation.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <section name="clientDependency" type="ClientDependency.Core.Config.ClientDependencySection, ClientDependency.Core" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Examine" type="Examine.Config.ExamineSettings, Examine" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="ExamineLuceneIndexSets" type="UmbracoExamine.Config.ExamineLuceneIndexes, UmbracoExamine" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="FileSystemProviders" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.FileSystemProvidersSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="BaseRestExtensions" type="Umbraco.Web.BaseRest.Configuration.BaseRestSection, umbraco" requirePermission="false" />

    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>

  <urlrewritingnet configSource="config\UrlRewriting.config" />
  <microsoft.scripting configSource="config\scripting.config" />
  <clientDependency configSource="config\ClientDependency.config" />
  <Examine configSource="config\ExamineSettings.config" />
  <ExamineLuceneIndexSets configSource="config\ExamineIndex.config" />
  <FileSystemProviders configSource="config\FileSystemProviders.config" />
  <log4net configSource="config\log4net.config" />
  <BaseRestExtensions configSource="config\BaseRestExtensions.config" />

  <appSettings>

    <add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="6.0.5" />
    <add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd" />
    <add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/" />
    <add key="umbracoContentXML" value="~/App_Data/umbraco.config" />
    <add key="umbracoStorageDirectory" value="~/App_Data" />
    <add key="umbracoPath" value="~/umbraco" />
    <add key="umbracoEnableStat" value="false" />
    <add key="umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath" value="true" />
    <add key="umbracoEditXhtmlMode" value="true" />
    <add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="false" />
    <add key="umbracoDebugMode" value="false" />
    <add key="umbracoTimeOutInMinutes" value="20" />
    <add key="umbracoVersionCheckPeriod" value="7" />
    <add key="umbracoDisableXsltExtensions" value="true" />
    <add key="umbracoDefaultUILanguage" value="en" />
    <add key="umbracoProfileUrl" value="profiler" />
    <add key="umbracoUseSSL" value="false" />
    <add key="umbracoUseMediumTrust" value="false" />

    <!-- Set this to true to enable storing the xml cache locally to the IIS server even if the app files are stored centrally on a SAN/NAS Alex Norcliffe 2010 02 for 4.1  -->
    <add key="umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp" value="false" />

    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />

    <add key="log4net.Config" value="config\log4net.config" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="127.0.0.1" userName="username" password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

  <connectionStrings>
   --not here anymore-- ;)
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Strict" />

    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

    <pages enableEventValidation="false">
      <!-- ASPNETAJAX -->
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="umbraco" namespace="umbraco.presentation.templateControls" assembly="umbraco" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <!-- URL REWRTIER -->
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
      <!-- UMBRACO -->
      <add name=" UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" />
      <!-- ASPNETAJAX -->
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <!-- CLIENT DEPENDENCY -->
      <add name="ClientDependencyModule" type="ClientDependency.Core.Module.ClientDependencyModule, ClientDependency.Core" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <!-- ASPNETAJAX -->
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <!-- UMBRACO CHANNELS -->
      <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.api, umbraco" />
      <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.wordApi, umbraco" />
      <!-- CLIENT DEPENDENCY -->
      <add verb="*" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core " />
      <!-- SPELL CHECKER -->
      <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="GoogleSpellChecker.ashx" type="umbraco.presentation.umbraco_client.tinymce3.plugins.spellchecker.GoogleSpellChecker,umbraco" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" batch="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <!-- ASP.NET 4.0 Assemblies -->
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>

      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
        <add extension=".vbhtml" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
        <add extension=".razor" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <!-- Membership Provider -->
    <membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <!-- added by NH to support membership providers in access layer -->
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!-- Sitemap provider-->
    <siteMap defaultProvider="UmbracoSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoSiteMapProvider" type="umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.UmbracoSiteMapProvider" defaultDescriptionAlias="description" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
        <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="F7FA540B4DFD82E5BB196B95D15FF81F4BA658F12F978BCF86ED0BA8B413F290" validation="SHA1" validationKey="4BA658F12F978BCF86ED0BA8B413F290629AD0E79DE62168764FF0DCE537184F0535D5D9AD66DEDC4BA658F12F978BCF86ED0BA8B413F290629AD0E797DC1ABF" />
  </system.web>

  <!-- ASPNETAJAX -->
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRewriteModule" />
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />

      <remove name="UmbracoModule" />
      <add name=" UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" />

      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

      <remove name="ClientDependencyModule" />
      <add name="ClientDependencyModule" type="ClientDependency.Core.Module.ClientDependencyModule, ClientDependency.Core" />

      <!-- Needed for login/membership to work on homepage (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218057/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-when-routing-requests) -->
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>

    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <remove name="Channels" />
      <remove name="Channels_Word" />
      <remove name="ClientDependency" />
      <remove name="SpellChecker" />

      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" name="Channels" preCondition="integratedMode" path="umbraco/channels.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.api, umbraco" />
      <add verb="*" name="Channels_Word" preCondition="integratedMode" path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.wordApi, umbraco" />
      <add verb="*" name="ClientDependency" preCondition="integratedMode" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core " />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" preCondition="integratedMode" name="SpellChecker" path="GoogleSpellChecker.ashx" type="umbraco.presentation.umbraco_client.tinymce3.plugins.spellchecker.GoogleSpellChecker,umbraco" />
    </handlers>

    <!-- Adobe AIR mime type -->
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".air" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <!-- Old asp.net ajax assembly bindings -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <!-- Ensure correct version of MVC -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorUmbracoFactory, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
    <pages pageBaseType="umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="umbraco" />
        <add namespace="Examine" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I assume you already changed your admin password, and made sure that there's no additional admin accounts on your installation that you're not using?

Comment: am changing my admin-pwd now and no other admins than my own account

Comment: Also the webhotel support staff is moving my site to a more secure server. To be continued...

Comment: It's possible that the problem isn't due to Umbraco, can your Host tell you how those files were uploaded/created in your hosting space? I worked for an office where an project manager's FTP account was compromised and multiple sites were filled with garbage similar to what you are describing.

Comment: I asked that very question an hour ago actually. Lets see what they come back with. I have changed password of the ftp a few times though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now also moved to a new server with bettet security, the hosting company could not find any logs of what happened. Crossing my fingers now that this does not happen again.