# Umbraco Client Dependency Handler Error

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, client-dependency

Actually my website works fine in my local system(IIS Express) with debug=true and debug=false, but when i have published to Production environment it gives a "**404 not found (dependency handler)**" error for the following request with `debug=false` set in the web.config:

`"/DependencyHandler.axd?s=L2Fzc2V0cy9wbHVnaW5zL2xheWVyX3NsaWRlci9jc......&t=Css&cdv=1"`

My Current Umbraco version is 7.3.0.

My Web.Config File is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="urlrewritingnet" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    <section name="microsoft.scripting" type="Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Configuration.Section, Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Examine" type="Examine.Config.ExamineSettings, Examine" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="ExamineLuceneIndexSets" type="Examine.LuceneEngine.Config.IndexSets, Examine" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="umbracoConfiguration">
      <section name="settings" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.UmbracoSettings.UmbracoSettingsSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="BaseRestExtensions" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.BaseRest.BaseRestSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="FileSystemProviders" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.FileSystemProvidersSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="dashBoard" type="Umbraco.Core.Configuration.Dashboard.DashboardSection, Umbraco.Core" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="clientDependency" type="ClientDependency.Core.Config.ClientDependencySection, ClientDependency.Core" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="imageProcessor">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Configuration.ImageSecuritySection, ImageProcessor.Web" />
      <section name="processing" requirePermission="false" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Configuration.ImageProcessingSection, ImageProcessor.Web" />
      <section name="cache" requirePermission="false" type="ImageProcessor.Web.Configuration.ImageCacheSection, ImageProcessor.Web" />
    </sectionGroup>    
  </configSections>
  <imageProcessor>
    <security configSource="config\imageprocessor\security.config" />
    <cache configSource="config\imageprocessor\cache.config" />
    <processing configSource="config\imageprocessor\processing.config" />
  </imageProcessor>
  <umbracoConfiguration>
    <settings configSource="config\umbracoSettings.config" />
    <BaseRestExtensions configSource="config\BaseRestExtensions.config" />
    <FileSystemProviders configSource="config\FileSystemProviders.config" />
    <dashBoard configSource="config\Dashboard.config" />
  </umbracoConfiguration>
  <urlrewritingnet configSource="config\UrlRewriting.config" />
  <microsoft.scripting configSource="config\scripting.config" />
  <Examine configSource="config\ExamineSettings.config" />
  <ExamineLuceneIndexSets configSource="config\ExamineIndex.config" />
  <log4net configSource="config\log4net.config" />
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Zbu.ModelsBuilder.ModelsNamespace" value="Zbu.BarniPost.Core.Models" />
    <add key="Zbu.ModelsBuilder.EnableAppDataModels" value="false" />
    <add key="Zbu.ModelsBuilder.EnableAppCodeModels" value="true" />
    <add key="Zbu.ModelsBuilder.EnableDllModels" value="false" />
    <add key="Zbu.ModelsBuilder.EnableApi" value="true" />
    <add key="Zbu.ModelsBuilder.EnableLiveModels" value="false" />
    <add key="umbracoVersionCheckPeriod" value="0" />
    <add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="7.3.0" />
    <add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd" />
    <add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/" />
    <add key="umbracoPath" value="~/umbraco" />
    <add key="umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath" value="true" />
    <add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="true" />
    <add key="umbracoTimeOutInMinutes" value="120" />
    <add key="umbracoDefaultUILanguage" value="en" />
    <add key="umbracoUseSSL" value="false" />
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="config\log4net.config" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="actionicon" value="" />
    <!--<add key="actionicon" value="info-circle" />-->
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup" />
    <add key="UploadDirectory" value="~/Uploads/Forms/Images" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />    
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="**************" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe" />
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>  
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="40960" />
    <!--
      If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
      you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
      change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
      of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" enableSessionState="true">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="umbraco" namespace="umbraco.presentation.templateControls" assembly="umbraco" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="ClientDependency.Core" />
        <add namespace="ClientDependency.Core.Mvc" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" />
      <add name="ClientDependencyModule" type="ClientDependency.Core.Module.ClientDependencyModule, ClientDependency.Core" />
      <add name="ImageProcessorModule" type="ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule, ImageProcessor.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.api, umbraco" />
      <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.wordApi, umbraco" />
      <add verb="GET" path="~/DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core " />
    </httpHandlers>
    <!--http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/developing-umbraco-7-packages/47004-Umb-7-Property-editor-controller-not-updating-->
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" batch="false" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Http" />
        <remove assembly="System.Net.Http" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Http" />
        <remove assembly="System.Net.Http" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Http" />
        <remove assembly="System.Net.Http" />
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="Zbu.ModelsBuilder" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
        <add extension=".vbhtml" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
        <add extension=".razor" type="umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorBuildProvider, umbraco.MacroEngines" />
        <add extension=".models" type="Zbu.ModelsBuilder.AspNet.ModelsBuildProvider, Zbu.ModelsBuilder.AspNet" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <!-- Membership Provider -->
    <membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <!-- Role Provider -->
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="BotDetect.Web.CustomSessionIdManager, BotDetect" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204800000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRewriteModule" />
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
      <remove name="UmbracoModule" />
      <add name="UmbracoModule" type="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule,umbraco" />
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <!-- Needed for login/membership to work on homepage (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218057/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-when-routing-requests) -->
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="ClientDependencyModule" />
      <add name="ClientDependencyModule" type="ClientDependency.Core.Module.ClientDependencyModule, ClientDependency.Core" />
      <add name="ImageProcessorModule" type="ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule, ImageProcessor.Web" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <remove name="Channels" />
      <remove name="Channels_Word" />
      <remove name="ClientDependency" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" name="Channels" preCondition="integratedMode" path="umbraco/channels.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.api, umbraco" />
      <add verb="*" name="Channels_Word" preCondition="integratedMode" path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.wordApi, umbraco" />
      <add verb="*" name="ClientDependency" preCondition="integratedMode" path="~/DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core " />
      <remove name="DependencyHandler" />
      <add name="DependencyHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET" path="~/DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core " requireAccess="Script" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- Adobe AIR mime type -->
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".air" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".less" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent>
    <!-- Ensure the powered by header is not returned -->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!-- Old asp.net ajax assembly bindings -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- Ensure correct version of MVC -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- Ensure correct version of HtmlAgilityPack -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.4.5.0-1.4.6.0" newVersion="1.4.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.7.0" newVersion="6.9.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <location path="umbraco">
    <system.webServer>
      <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="App_Plugins">
    <system.webServer>
      <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <clientDependency version="1621990453">
    <!-- Full config documentation is here: https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency/wiki/Configuration -->
  </clientDependency>
</configuration>
```

Please Suggest my any solutions.

I have already post the same query at [here](https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency/issues/78)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got my solution at [here](https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency/issues/78).

Please find the solution from [here](https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency/issues/78). Thank you Shazwazza!

Comment: Could you explain what is the solution, not only providing links?

Comment: Yes Sure. Actually, I missed that declaration of clientdependency config. I mean to say this line - 
<clientDependency configSource="config\ClientDependency.config" />

Answer (score 0):

check your web.config file
`<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" batch="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50">`

when you change `debug="false"` the dependency handler stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolve it by changing the value in the following file.

```
/wwwroot/config/ClientDependency.config
```

> `<clientDependency version=".....">`

by changing the value +1